# What does this function represent?

Tags: real-analysis

Im having trouble understanding what this function represent $ F(x)= \sum_{i=1}^{5} \{x \leq i \} $.

I get that it is the sum $F(x)=\{x \leq 1 \} +....+\{x\leq 5 \} $. But whats the intuition of $\{x \leq i\}$?

Comment: Are you aware of the indicator function that takes on values either $0$ or $1$.

Comment: Ah okay yea I think so, but shouldnt the notation be $1_{ \{ x \leq i \}}$ then, or does both work?

So $\{x \leq i \}= 1$ if $x\leq i $, else its 0?

Comment: Using $1_{\{x \le i\}}$ is more appropriate.

Comment: So then $F(x)=\sum_{i=1}^5 \{x \leq i \} = 1_{\{x \leq 5\}}$, its 1 if $x\leq 5$ for other values its 0?

Comment: I think $F(x) = \sum_{i=1}^{5} \{x \le i\}= \sum_{i=1}^{5} 1_{\{x \le i\}}$. So $F(0)=5$, $F(1.5)=4$, and $F(10)=0$ etc.